# Cast VARCHAR columns to int, bigint, time, etc (PL/pgSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

### Problem

(This is for an open source, analytics library.)

Here's our query results from `events_view`:

```
  id  | visit_id |  name  |             prop0          | prop1 | url
------+----------+--------+----------------------------+-------+------------
 2004 |        4 | Magnus | 2021-10-26 02:25:55.790999 | 142   | cnn.com
 2007 |        4 | Hartis | 2021-10-26 02:26:37.773999 | 25    | fox.com
```

Currently all columns are `VARCHAR`.

```
  Column  |        Type       | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id       | bigint            |           |          |
 visit_id | character varying |           |          |
 name     | character varying |           |          |
 prop0    | character varying |           |          |
 prop1    | character varying |           |          |
 url      | character varying |           |          |
```

They **should** be something like

```
  Column  |           Type         | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id       | bigint                 |           |          |
 visit_id | bigint                 |           |          |
 name     | character varying      |           |          |
 prop0    | time without time zone |           |          |
 prop1    | bigint                 |           |          |
 url      | character varying      |           |          |
```

### Desired result

Hardcoding these castings as in `SELECT visit::bigint, name::varchar, prop0::time, prop1::integer, url::varchar FROM tbl` won't do, column names are known in run time only.

To simplify things we could cast each column into only three types: **boolean**, **numeric**, or **varchar**. Use regexps below for matching types:

- boolean: `^(true|false|t|f)$`
- numeric: `^(,-)[0-9]+(,\.[0-9]+)$`
- varchar: every result that does not match boolean and numeric above

What should be the SQL that discover what type each column is and *dynamically* cast them?

Comment: Unrelated: are you really using PostgreSQL 9.4? It reached EOL long time ago.

Comment: What if a column contains several different detected data types?

Comment: @jarlh we'll match against a regexp to identify, to simplify use column's first non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

These are a few ideas rather than a true solution for this tricky job. A slow but very reliable function can be used instead of regular expressions.

```sql
create or replace function can_cast(s text, vtype text)
returns boolean language plpgsql immutable as 
$body$
begin
    execute format('select %L::%s', s, vtype);
    return true;
exception when others then
    return false;
end;
$body$;
```

Data may be presented like this (partial list of columns from your example)

```sql
create or replace temporary view tv(id, visit_id, prop0, prop1) as
values
(
    2004::bigint,
    4::bigint, 
    case when can_cast('2021-10-26 02:25:55.790999', 'time') then '2021-10-26 02:25:55.790999'::time end,
    case when can_cast('142', 'bigint') then '142'::bigint end
), -- determine the types
(2007, 4, '2021-10-26 02:26:37.773999', 25)
-- the rest of the data here;
```

I believe that it is possible to generate the temporary view DDL dynamically as a `select` from `events_view` too.

Comment: Good insight, I found a solution for my problem building for each attribute/column a table with candidate types then picking the ones with most valid values. Quite complicated and slow but works.